# AVAudioPlayer.duration not equal AVURLAsset.duration

Tags: avaudioplayer, avurlasset

I record a audio file by `AVAudioEngin`, with out-format:

`@{                                                                               AVSampleRateKey:@(44100.0),
AVNumberOfChannelsKey: @(1),
AVFormatIDKey: @(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC),                                                                               }`,

Then I playback it with `AVAudioPlayer` ,

```
self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:self.outFilePath] error:nil];
NSTimeInterval duration = _player.duration; // 409.73357109834228

AVURLAsset*audioAsset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.outFilePath] options:nil];
CMTime audioDuration = audioAsset.duration;
Float64 seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(audioDuration); // 429.31374149659865
```

why `duration` is not equal to `seconds`?

Did i missed some properties to set for `AVAudioPlayer`?

Answer (score 0):

i see some options at AVAsset.h, about the duration property. as below:

`Indicates the duration of the asset. If @"providesPreciseDurationAndTiming" is NO, a best-available estimate of the duration is returned. The degree of precision preferred for timing-related properties can be set at initialization time for assets initialized with URLs. See AVURLAssetPreferPreciseDurationAndTimingKey for AVURLAsset below.`

it tells that when the **providesPreciseDurationAndTiming** is NO, the duration is not exactly correct, you should set **providesPreciseDurationAndTiming** to YES, just have a try.

Comment: hi, george . `player.duration = 411.18098`.  set   `providesPreciseDurationAndTiming  : @(NO)` then `seconds = 430.823`; and set `providesPreciseDurationAndTiming  : @(YES)` then `seconds = 436.535`; and the audio file length in Finder is 07:10 (430 s).